# Combining JSON files without extra brackets

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

I have two identical json files - `test.json` and `test2.json` in the exact format as below.  My goal is to combine them and keep the exact same format  - just basically stack one on top of the other without creating two lists.

I am new to bash and jq but this code throws an error:

```
jq -s '.[0] * .[1]' test.json test2.json

jq: error (at test2.json:17): array ([{"vendor":...) and array ([{"vendor":...) cannot be multiplied
```

Why does this happen and how does one preserve the format without writing extra brackets `[]`.  How does one combine and keep only one pair of brackets around the entire file?  See below:

`test.json`:

```
[
  {
    "vendor": 0,
    "startTime": 4380,
    "endTime": 4445
  },
  {
    "vendor": 0,
    "startTime": 4448,
    "endTime": 4453
  },
  {
    "vendor": 0,
    "startTime": 4696,
    "endTime": 4880
  }
]
```

undesired output:

```
[
  [
    {"vendor":0,"startTime":4380,"endTime":4445},
    {"vendor":0,"startTime":4448,"endTime":4453},
    {"vendor":0,"startTime":4696,"endTime":4880}],

    [{"vendor":0,"startTime":4380,"endTime":4445},
      {"vendor":0,"startTime":4448,"endTime":4453},
      {"vendor":0,"startTime":4696,"endTime":4880}
  ]
]
```

desired output:

```
  [
    {"vendor":0,"startTime":4380,"endTime":4445},
    {"vendor":0,"startTime":4448,"endTime":4453},
    {"vendor":0,"startTime":4696,"endTime":4880},
    {"vendor":0,"startTime":4380,"endTime":4445},
    {"vendor":0,"startTime":4448,"endTime":4453},
    {"vendor":0,"startTime":4696,"endTime":4880}
  ]
```

Comment: what command do you use for the task? bash may be might on this, other  language like Python could done this very easily, if you like I could shoot you a script very quickly though

Comment: sorry forgot to include it - updated- thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following invocation produces the desired result:

```
jq -s add input.json input.json
```

In brief, the -s ("slurp") option places all the top-level input JSON entities into an array, producing an array of arrays in the present case.  `add` then "adds" the components of this array -- `add` being polymorphic  has the effect here of concatenating the component arrays.

If your jq has `inputs`, you could similarly write:

```
jq -n '[inputs]|add' input.json input.json

or:

jq -n '[inputs[]]' input.json input.json
```

By the way, there are other ways to pass the JSON in the files into jq.

Answer (score -2):

I have naver use the `jq` command

But you could do this very easily with a python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Author:    
# Maintainer: 
import simplejson as json

def test():
    with open("test.json") as fp:
        js1 = json.loads(fp.read())
        with open("test2.json") as fp1:
            js2 = json.loads(fp1.read())
            js = js1 + js2
            print(json.dumps(js, indent=4))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()

# vim:ai:et:sts=4:sw=4:
```

Note the only thing you might have to do is install the `simplejson` package with

`sudo pip install simplejson`

since it might not shipped with your distribution, good luck

Comment: `simplejson` has been part of the standard library as `json` since Python 2.6. `json.load` takes a file-like object; no need to call `read` manually.  There's also no need to keep `test.json` open once you've parsed it, so don't nest the `with` statements.